# How to capture network related logs with in the android phone

Tags: android, logging, page-load-time

I want to know how to capture logs with in mobile phone

Does this network logs can be used to measure page load time ?

I tried capturing device logs using adb logcat in desktop but I want to capture those logs with in device

Comment: So if you are capturing the logs "using adb logcat in desktop" then what's the problem? If you're doing that then you have the data. Just use it however you want.

Comment: the problem here is, from desktop using appium i will be automating few apps at the same time i can't capture the logs and run automation. Is there any way to capture the network logs with in the phone

Comment: I mean, you could just save that information to a file on the phone. Like write it to a text file or whatever.

Comment: yes. i want to save log related information with in the phone

Comment: In that case, see my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your logs are located in a String file, you can save them to a text file like this:

```
private void saveLogsToFile(String logs) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("saved_logs.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        out.write(logs);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then read them back from the file like this:

```
private String readSavedLogs() {
    String logs = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("saved_logs.txt");
        if(inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
            String line;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            logs = stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return logs;
}
```